# Flutter Tabs "Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I use standard tabs after a few of my blocks. The content in the tabs is styled using a container. The main parent element is Column in which I build all my blocks. I have tried various options using Expanded.
The error sometimes changes to "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded." This only happens when i try to add tabs, any other block is displayed correctly in my main Column.

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
            ),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: < Widget > [
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                hintText: 'Найти услугу...',
                                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                        height: 450,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/ps-bg.png"),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: < Widget > [
                                SvgPicture.asset(
                                    'assets/ps-logo.svg',
                                ),
                                Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                                            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                            colors: [
                                                Color.fromRGBO(6, 85, 152, 0),
                                                Color(0xFF084A82),
                                            ],
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    child: CarouselSlider(
                                        options: CarouselOptions(
                                            autoPlay: false,
                                            aspectRatio: 16 / 10,
                                            enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                            viewportFraction: 0.6,
                                        ),
                                        items: imgList.map((item) => LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                                            return ClipRRect(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                                ),
                                                child: Stack(
                                                    children: < Widget > [
                                                        Container(
                                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                                            child: Column(
                                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                                children: < Widget > [
                                                                    Image.asset(
                                                                        'assets/psplus-1month.png',
                                                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                                                        height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                                                                    ),
                                                                    SizedBox(height: 23),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                        'Playstation Plus',
                                                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                            color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                        ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                        '1 месяц',
                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                            color: const Color(0xFFA5ABC8),
                                                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                                        ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                        '1 500 рублей',
                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                            color: const Color(0xFF789EEB),
                                                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                                        ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                                ],
                                                            ),
                                                        ),
                                                        Positioned(
                                                            bottom: constraints.maxHeight / 2 - 18,
                                                            left: 0.0,
                                                            right: 0.0,
                                                            child: Column(
                                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                                                children: < Widget > [
                                                                    Container(
                                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                            color: Colors.green,
                                                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                                            boxShadow: [
                                                                                BoxShadow(
                                                                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                                                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.10),
                                                                                    spreadRadius: 2)
                                                                            ],
                                                                        ),
                                                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                                            radius: 18,
                                                                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                                                                        ),
                                                                    )
                                                                ],
                                                            ),
                                                        ),
                                                    ],
                                                ),
                                            );
                                        }, ), ).toList()
                                    )
                                ),
                            ]
                        ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    DefaultTabController(
                        length: 3,
                        child: Column(
                            children: [
                                Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                                    child: TabBar(
                                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), // Creates border
                                            color: const Color(0xFF62A6E9)
                                        ),
                                        labelColor: Colors.white,
                                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
                                        tabs: [
                                            Tab(text: 'Инструкция'),
                                            Tab(text: 'Оплаты'),
                                            Tab(text: 'Информация'),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                                TabBarView(
                                    children: [
                                        Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                                'Text',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                                        height: 1.5,
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                                'Text',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                                        height: 1.5,
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                                'Text',
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                                        height: 1.5,
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                ),
                            ]
                        )
                    ),
                    GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        children: List.generate(10, (index) {
                            return Container(
                                child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                                        child: Stack(
                                            children: < Widget > [
                                                Image.network(
                                                    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    width: 1000.0),
                                                Positioned(
                                                    bottom: 0.0,
                                                    left: 0.0,
                                                    right: 0.0,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                                        children: < Widget > [
                                                            Container(
                                                                decoration:
                                                                BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                    top: 15.0,
                                                                    bottom: 15.0
                                                                ),
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                    'PUBG',
                                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: const Color(0xFF4F4F4F),
                                                                            fontSize: 16,
                                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                    ),
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                                        ],
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                                Positioned(
                                                    bottom: 40.0,
                                                    left: 0.0,
                                                    right: 0.0,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                                        children: < Widget > [
                                                            CircleAvatar(
                                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                                radius: 15,
                                                                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                                                            ),
                                                        ],
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                            ],
                                        )),
                                ),
                            );
                        }),
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found solution, TabBarView need height, Expanded not help.

```
Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: TabBarView(
        children: [
            Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            Icon(Icons.directions_car)
        ],
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in LayoutBuilder:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (_, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
        ),
        child: Column(),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Its give me another error "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."

Comment: @Elexer I have changed the answer. Try LayoutBuilder. This works great in my project

Comment: Again Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height. lol, when I remove the tabs everything works

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/YS2XsVzS/Screenshot-1617954328.png

Comment: Problem in TabBarView 100%

Comment: @Elexer You need to clear the widget tree, then add one widget at a time. So you'll find the problem

Comment: I did just that, the problem is exactly in TabBarView

Comment: @Elexer You can try to add the height of the Container above the TabBar